# Regular expression using re.compile

Tags: python-3.x

I want the word 'a' to be capitalized for the below scenarios

if 'a' is in between 2 single characters or is followed by a single character and is the end of sentence or is followed by a number or alphanumeric, then it should be capitalised. How can I achieve this?

```
r a t             -->        r A t
It is r a t xxx   -->        It is r A t xxx
It is r a         -->        It is r A
It is r a(space)  -->        It is r a
Itisr a t         -->        Itisr a t
Itisr a txxx      -->        Itisr a txxx
It is r a txxx    -->        It is r a txxx
```

I have used the below logic but it doesnt seem to work for few of the cases. Can you please help.

```
pattern = re.compile(r"^(.* [A-Za-z] )(a)( [A-Za-z] *.*)")
match = pattern.search(inputstring)  #//inputstring is above string
if match:
      inputstring = f'{match.group(1)}{match.group(2).capitalize()}{match.group(3)}'
```

Comment: When you say *"or is followed by a single character and is the end of sentence "*, do you mean `"hello a d"` or `"hello d a"`?

Comment: When you say *"or is followed by a number or alphanumeric"*, do you mean any of `"hello a d"`, `"hello a 3"`, `"hello p a "`, etc.?

Comment: Hi Ann, It means as in the example "It is r a"

Answer (score 0):

```
e = "It is r a txxx h  u ".split()

f = " ".join(e)
for i in range(len(e)):
    if i == 0 or i == len(e) - 1:
        continue
    if len(e[i - 1]) == 1 and len(e[i + 1]) == 1 and len(e[i]) == 1:
        if e[i - 1].islower() and e[i + 1].islower():
            e[i] = e[i].upper()
            f = " ".join(e)

print(f)
```

this is what you wanted?

Comment: I am looking to use re.compile as rest of my code uses these functions. Are you able to help with a logic using same?

Comment: sorry i don't use re but you can use the logic of my code in re

Answer (score 0):

For this case, I will use [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module instead of Python's `re`, because the latter only support fixed-width look mechanics.

```
import regex

s = """r a t
It is r a t xxx
It is r a
It is r a                   #'a' followed by a space
Itisr a t
Itisr a txxx
It is r a txxx"""

n = s.split('\n')

r = regex.compile(r'((?<=\b\w(\s)*\b)a(?=\b(\s)*\w\b)|((?<=\b\w(\s)*\b)a$))')

for j in n:
    if r.search(j) != None:
        g = r.search(j).span()
        print(''.join(z if y != g[0] else 'A' for y, z in enumerate(j)))
```

```
r A t
It is r A t xxx
It is r A
```

While this may solve the problem, some caution is warranted.

Comment: if I want to apply this rule to all occurances of 'a' how can I do? For example, in case of 'r a t a p a' it should be 'r A t A p A'.